# Maximum curvature problem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

> $f(x) = \frac{ax^3}{6}$, $a > 0,$ $0 \le x < +\infty  $ and the 
>   maximum of its curvature equals $\frac{1}{1000}$. Find x at which this
>   maximum curvature is reached.

What I was trying to do:

$f'(x) = ax^2/2$

$f''(x) = ax$

Therefore, $k = \frac{|ax|}{\sqrt(1 + \frac{a^2 x^4}{4})^3} = \frac{ax}{\sqrt(1 + \frac{a^2 x^4}{4})^3} $
Then, knowing that $max(k) = \frac{1}{1000}$, I was going to find $a$, and that is where I stuck, because I ended up with some really unplesant stuff and gave up :(

Is there any smarter ways to solve this problem and was my way correct at all?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the value of $x$ that maximises curvature $k$, you can differentiate w.r.t. $x$ and set this to zero. The resulting expression will be quite complicated.

However, note that the $\log$ function is monotonic, so we can differentiate $\log k$ w.r.t $x$, and set this to zero. This will result in a far nicer expression.

Taking the log results in
$$\log k = \log ax - \frac{3}{2}\log\left(1+\frac{a^2x^4}{4}\right)$$ 
So that
$$\frac{d\log k}{dx}=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{3}{2}\left(\frac{4a^2x^3}{4+a^2x^4}\right)$$
Setting this to zero results in
$$a^2x^4=\frac{4}{5}\Rightarrow x=\frac{2^{1/2}}{5^{1/4}a^{1/2}}$$
Substituting these back into $k$ and setting this to $\frac{1}{1000}$:-

$$\frac{(2a)^{1/2}}{5^{1/4}(1+\frac{1}{5})^{3/2}}=\frac{1}{1000}\Rightarrow a=\frac{5^{1/2}6^3}{2(10^6)(5^3)}$$
Thus 
$$x=\frac{2^{1/2}}{5^{1/4}a^{1/2}}=\frac{2(10^3)(5)}{6^{3/2}}=\frac{10^4}{6\sqrt{6}}=\frac{5\times10^3}{3\sqrt{6}}$$

Comment: Thank you a lot! A very nice way to make the resulting expression less complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Solve $\frac{ax}{\sqrt{(1+\frac{a^2x^4}{4})^3}}=\frac{1}{1000}$

$\Rightarrow ax=\frac{1}{1000}\sqrt{(1+\frac{a^2x^4}{4})^3}$

$\Rightarrow a^2x^2=\frac{1}{100,000}(1+\frac{a^2x^4}{4})^3$

Let $z=(x^2)/2$ and we have:

$2a^2z=\frac{1}{100,000}(1+a^2z^2)^3=\frac{1}{100,000}(1+3a^2z^2+3a^4z^4+a^6z^6)$

$\Rightarrow 1+200,000z+3a^2z^2+3a^4z^4+a^6z^6=0$

This doesn't seem to be very nice, and wolfram doesn't even seem to like finding the roots:

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+for+z%2C+1%2B200%2C000z%2B3a%5E2z%5E2%2B3a%5E4z%5E4%2Ba%5E6z%5E6%3D0

But hopefully this helps!